# Eggs & heart health?

Tags: diet, cardiology, heart-disease, cardiovascular-disease

How does egg consumption impact atherosclerosis/cardiovascular disease risk? I'd especially welcome experimental studies.

Comment: That's a terse and yet broad question. If you could expand on your current research and reasoning? e.g. Is it mainly about cholesterol in chicken eggs?

Comment: Maybe cardiology testing has been done on UK islands where they live on sea bird eggs for months and then eat preserved eggs the rest of the year.

Comment: Exactly! I'm curious about the impact of chicken egg consumption, assuming (nearly) vacuum sealed experimental conditions. Eggs contain a mix of MUFAs, PUFAs, sat, & trans fats, etc...What's their rough net effect?

Comment: You did go through these: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=egg+consumption+atherosclerosis+cardiovascular+disease+risk, did you?

Comment: I had not. Just getting around to looking into this question; apologies for my laziness.

Comment: [They don't eat many eggs here](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2017/mar/17/tsimane-of-the-bolivian-amazon-have-worlds-healthiest-hearts-says-study).

Answer (score 2):

Consumption of 1-2 eggs per day is not associated with an increased risk of cardiovascular disease, according to the following systematic reviews of studies:

[Egg consumption in relation to risk of cardiovascular disease and diabetes: a systematic review and meta-analysis (AJCN, 2013)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23676423):

> This meta-analysis suggests that egg consumption is not associated
>   with the risk of CVD and cardiac mortality in the general population.
>   However, egg consumption may be associated with an increased incidence
>   of type 2 diabetes among the general population and CVD comorbidity
>   among diabetic patients.

[Impact of Egg Consumption on Cardiovascular Risk Factors in Individuals with Type 2 Diabetes and at Risk for Developing Diabetes: A Systematic Review of Randomized Nutritional Intervention Studies (Canadian Journal of Diabetes, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28359773):

> Results from randomized controlled trials suggest that consumption of
>   6 to 12 eggs per week, in the context of a diet that is consistent
>   with guidelines on cardiovascular health promotion, has no adverse
>   effect on major CVD [cardiovascular] risk factors in individuals at risk for developing
>   diabetes or with type 2 diabetes. However, heterogeneities in study
>   design, population included and interventions prevent firm conclusions
>   from being drawn.

[Egg Consumption and Human Cardio-Metabolic Health in People with and without Diabetes (Nutrients, 2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4586539/):

> A high egg diet in the context of a background diet that is low in
>   saturated fats (a polyunsaturated to saturated fat ratio > 0.7), or a
>   diet that replaces saturated fats with poly- and mono-unsaturated
>   fats, is likely to result in positive or no adverse changes in LDL
>   cholesterol, and could be safely advised.

You can also check [this answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/19584/3002).

In *some* individuals, consumption of eggs, which are high in cholesterol, may increase LDL cholesterol levels and thus increase the risk of cardiovascular disease [(Nutrients, 2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4586539/). In *most* individuals, high cholesterol intake is not associated with high blood cholesterol levels, though.

[Dietary Cholesterol, Serum Lipids, and Heart Disease: Are Eggs Working for or Against You? (Nutrients, 2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5946211/):

> Overall, recent intervention studies with eggs demonstrate that the
>   additional dietary cholesterol does not negatively affect serum
>   lipids, and in some cases, appears to improve lipoprotein particle
>   profiles and HDL functionality.